# Cycles menu doesn't have setting required

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I am working on a project following a tutorial from polygon runway on youtube. As I rendered my image it was really grainy. I search net to solve the problem. One thing I saw is to set your settings on GPU commute. My Blender file doesn't not show that option in *Properties Panel > Render Menu*.

Though if I open a new file it does show those settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t select the GPU in the render options, go to Edit > Preferences, then I think it’s System. There you will have boxes like CUDA, OpenCL etc. If you have a graphics card, it will be under one of those options. Make sure you check the box for it. Then you can go back to the render settings and you should be able to select your GPU.

Also, enabling the GPU won’t neccesarily give your renders less noise. It will just render faster than the CPU, which allows you to use higher samples for less noise.